# Manipulate python django dictionary content

Tags: python, html, json, django

I am developing a simple weather application using Django. I am able to display city name, temp, wind speed, description of condition, and add/delete cities. When a city is added, the web app displays a card with that City name and all of those weather information described above.

Being a rower, I would like to add a "safeToRow" section to a cities card. That section will take in the temperature and wind of the city from the python dictionary and assign it to two variables. Then run those variables through some simple if and else if conditions to determine is it's safe to row and finally returning the final value of safeToRow.

Views.py

```
def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&units=imperial&appid=APIKEY'


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    cities = City.objects.all()

    weather_data = []

    safeToRow = ""


    for city in cities:

        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

        city_weather = {
            'city' : city.name,
            'temperature' : r['main']['temp'],
            'wind' : r['wind']['speed'],
            'description' : r['weather'][0]['description'],
            'icon' : r['weather'][0]['icon'],
        }

        weather_data.append(city_weather)


        temp = r['main']['temp']
        wind = r['wind']['speed']


        def row(temp, wind, safeToRow):
            if temp < 32:
                return safeToRow == "No"
            elif temp > 40 and wind < 15:
                return safeToRow == "No"
            elif temp < 40 and wind > 15:
                return safeToRow == "Yes"



    context = {'weather_data' : weather_data, 'form' : form, "safeToRow" : safeToRow}
    return render(request, 'weather/weather.html', context)
```

HTML portion

```
<div class="media-content">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <p>
                                        <span class="title">{{ city_weather.city }}</span>
                                        <br> 
                                        <span class="subtitle">{{ city_weather.temperature }}</span>
                                        <br> 
                                        <span class="subtitle">{{ city_weather.row }}</span>
                                        <br> 
                                        <span class="subtitle">{{ city_weather.wind }}</span>
                                        <br> {{ city_weather.description }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

It makes the section on the card on the web app, but the section is blank

Comment: You have a `row()` function but never used it.

Comment: In your `context`, you store weather under `.weather_data`, but access `{{ city_weather.whatever }}` in the template. Do you have a loop over `weather_data` in the template?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call city_weather.row but you have row defined as a function.